# Does write statement in Fortran90 affect resulting variable?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I know write statement is just to print the variable. But I have found something in my code.
For example, there are two variables called 'T_avg' and 'T_favg.'
I wanted to print T_favg, I used the line below.

`write(*,*) T_favg` 
result: 100

And then I also wanted to see T_avg, I added variable.

`write(*,*) T_avg, T_favg`
result: 50, 200

I did not modify the code at all except that line, but the result of T_favg is different.

I used this command line.
`ifort.exe /O2 scale_analysis(07022020).f90 -o test.exe`

Is there any circumstance occurring it?
**Sorry, I added my code.

```
PROGRAM scale_analysis
    USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_fortran_env, ONLY: real32, real64, FILE_STORAGE_SIZE
    IMPLICIT NONE
    
    ! DECLARE PARAMETERS
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: SP = real32       ! SINGLE-PRECISION REAL
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP = real64       ! DOUBLE-PRECISION REAL
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nx = 1024         ! TOTAL NUMBER OF GRID POINTS
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: iskip = 2
    
     
    ! DECLARE ALLOCATABLE ARRAYS
    REAL(SP), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:,:) :: STMP, T, RHO
    
    ! DECLARE VARIABLES FOR SUMMATION
    REAL(SP) :: rho_sum, rhoT_sum, T_sum
    
    ! DECLARE VARIABLES FOR REYNOLDS-AVERAGING
    REAL(SP) :: rho_avg, rhoT_avg, T_avg
    
    ! DECLARE VARIABLES FOR FAVRE-AVERAGING
    REAL(SP) :: T_favg
    
    INTEGER :: i, j, k
    
    CHARACTER(LEN=100) :: outfile, varname, infile4, infile5
    CHARACTER(LEN=100) :: filename
    
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! DEMONSTRATE READ_DATA
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    ALLOCATE(T(nx/iskip, nx/iskip, nx/iskip))
    ALLOCATE(RHO(nx/iskip, nx/iskip, nx/iskip))
    ALLOCATE(STMP(nx, nx, nx))

    STMP = 0.0_SP
    
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! INITIALIZATION OF SUMMATION VARIABLES
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    rho_sum = 0.0;     rhoT_sum = 0.0;     
    T_sum = 0.0;        
    T_avg = 0.0;        T_favg = 0.0;
    
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! DATA IMPORT -START
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    varname = 'Z1_dil_inertHIT'
    outfile = 'terms_in_Kolla(Z1_inertHIT).txt'
    infile4 = 'E:\AUTOIGNITION\Z1\Temperature_inertHIT.bin'
    infile5 = 'E:\AUTOIGNITION\Z1\Density_inertHIT.bin'
    
    
    
    OPEN(44, file=TRIM(ADJUSTL(infile4)), status='old', access='stream', &
         form='unformatted')
    READ(44) stmp
    CLOSE(44)
    DO k = 1, nx/iskip
        DO j = 1, nx/iskip
            DO i = 1, nx/iskip
                T(i,j,k) = stmp(1+iskip*(i-1), 1+iskip*(j-1), 1+iskip*(k-1)) 
            END DO
        END DO
    END DO
    WRITE(*, '(A)') 'Data4 is successfully read ... '
    
    OPEN(55, file=TRIM(ADJUSTL(infile5)), status='old', access='stream', &
         form='unformatted')
    READ(55) stmp
    CLOSE(55)
    DO k = 1, nx/iskip
        DO j = 1, nx/iskip
            DO i = 1, nx/iskip
                RHO(i,j,k) = stmp(1+iskip*(i-1), 1+iskip*(j-1), 1+iskip*(k-1)) 
            END DO
        END DO
    END DO
    WRITE(*, '(A)') 'Data5 is successfully read ... '
    
    DEALLOCATE(stmp)
    
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! COMPUTE U_RMS
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DO k = 1, nx/iskip
        DO j = 1, nx/iskip
            DO i = 1, nx/iskip
                rho_sum = rho_sum + RHO(i,j,k)
            END DO
        END DO
    END DO

    rho_avg = rho_sum / REAL((nx/iskip)**3)

    
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! COMPUTE TEMPERATRUE TAYLOR LENGTH SCALE(LAMBDA_T)
    ! C.TOWERY, DETONATION INITIATION BY COMPRESSIBLE TURBULENCE THERMODYNAMIC
    ! FLUCTUATIONS, CNF, 2019
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DO k = 1, nx/iskip
        DO j = 1, nx/iskip
            DO i = 1, nx/iskip
                T_sum = T_sum + T(i,j,k)
                rhoT_sum = rhoT_sum + ( RHO(i,j,k)*T(i,j,k) )
            END DO
        END DO
    END DO
    
    T_avg = T_sum / REAL((nx/iskip)**3)
    rhoT_avg = rhoT_sum / REAL((nx/iskip)**3)
    T_favg = rhoT_avg / rho_avg
    
    DO k = 1, nx/iskip
        DO j = 1, nx/iskip
            DO i = 1, nx/iskip
                rhoT_p_sum = rhoT_p_sum + RHO(i,j,k)*( (T(i,j,k) - T_favg)**2 )
            END DO
        END DO
    END DO
    
    rhoT_p_avg = rhoT_p_sum / REAL((nx/iskip)**3)
   
    T_p = SQRT( rhoT_p_avg / rho_avg )
    
    write(*,*) T_favg

    write(*,*) T_avg,T_favg

END PROGRAM scale_analysis
```

The problematic part is write statement. If I erase T_avg from the second write statement line, then T_favg changes.

Comment: We need to see that actual lines of Fortran code including the declaration of the variables.

Comment: Welcome, but without knowing how you declared the variables, initialized them etc. it is impossible to say something sensible about it. Please add a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing your problem.

Comment: Please note the minimal of the link mentioned by me, i.e. try yourself by removing not relevant code to still see the problem. And like francescalus compile with runtime checks, especially checks for checking the boundaries of the arrays.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments. I added -CB (Performs run-time checks on whether array  subscript  and  sub-string  references  are  within  declared  bounds) in command line, and clearly it shows different result. Can anyone explain to me why this command is needed?

Comment: the `-CB` / `-check bounds` should not give different results (which version of `ifort` are you using?). Please try with and without the option (maybe it is that your question is based on something else tan the current program, just a wild guess).

Comment: I am using Version 19.1.0.166. With -CB, T_favg is same regardless T_avg. Without -CB,  T_favg changes when there is T_avg in the write statement.

Comment: The variable `rhoT_p_sum` seems to be uninitialized. That should not affect `T_favg` however. But it seems like an out-of-bounds, or initialization problem.